# Flask on Windows powershell

Tags: python, powershell, flask

i have installed flask and i am trying to run flask using the windows power shell
but i am unable to do so

```
PS C:\path\to\app> $env:FLASK_APP = "hello.py"
```

the format is given the documentation what should we type in `$env`?

p.s. I was able to run flask using command prompt using the code

Comment: `& $env:FLASK_APP` to call it or just `$env:FLASK_APP` to see the string value.

Comment: my virtual environment name is Kintsu so if i want to run it on powershell do i have to type $Kitsu:Flask_APP

Comment: `env` is a psdrive provided by the environment when PowerShell is started. The expression parser allows you to access environment variables using the syntax `$env:variable` rather than the more verbose `(Get-ChildItem env:variable).Value`.

Answer (score 3):

- first, you have to activate the virtual environment for your `Flask` app (i'm assuming you are using `venv` the default virtual environment module for python : `py -m venv venv`)

```
PS C:\myapps\flask\helloflask> .\venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) PS C:\myapps\flask\helloflask>
```

- set the `FLASK_APP` environment variable:

```
(venv) PS C:\myapps\flask\helloflask> $env:FLASK_APP="helloflask:create_app('development')"
```

note the double quotes wrapping the app name `"helloflask:create_app('development')"` otherwise `Power Shell` triggers a red error.

refer to this [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/) on using **app factory pattern** and i would recommend you this [good reads](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-run-flask-application) on **How to Run a Flask Application**

- maybe you want to check if `FLASK_APP` has been set:

```
(venv) PS C:\myapps\flask\helloflask> $env:FLASK_APP
helloflask:create_app('development')
```

- now you can run your `Flask` app:

```
(venv) PS C:\myapps\flask\helloflask> flask run
 * Serving Flask app "helloflask:create_app('development')"
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2020 12:47:20] "←[37mGET / HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
```

finally i recommend you using `.flaskenv` under the root of your project to store your `Flask` app related environment variables (`FLASK_APP` among others):

## /.flaskenv

```
FLASK_APP=helloflask:create_app('development')
# FLASK_APP=helloflask:create_app('testing')
# FLASK_APP=helloflask:create_app('production')

FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_DEBUG=0

# FLASK_RUN_EXTRA_FILES=
# FLASK_RUN_HOST=
# FLASK_RUN_PORT=8080
# FLASK_RUN_CERT=
# FLASK_RUN_KEY=
```

To take advantage of this option you have to install the `python-dotenv` package (have a look at this [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/installation/#optional-dependencies)). To do so :

```
(venv) PS C:\mypps\flask\helloflask> pip install python-dotenv
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will still be usefull but this is how I got mine to work.

1. In powershell type:
   `.venv/Scripts/activate`  and press Enter
   In the comand line make sure you see something like: (.env) if so then type:
2. `$env:FLASK_APP = "yourappname.py"` and press Enter then type
3. `$env:FLASK_ENV = "development"` and finally type
4. `flask run`